# Concatenating columns in Pandas DataFrame, deleting concatenated ones

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

I got a DataFrame with weather Data from a whole year, one line being the data for a Day. Now I want to concatenate the rain and snow data as precipitation and delete concatenated ones. Looking through stackoverflow I came up with the following:

```
    data is from a different function:

    df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep=' ', names=['Year', 'Month', 'Day', 'o Temp', 'Min Temp', 'Max Temp', 'Rain', 'Snow',
                                               'wind_dir', 'wind_speed', 'Air Pressure', 'temp_sun'])
```

df is stored in data and afterwards used as followed:

```
    for day in data:
        data['Precepitation'] = data['Rain'] + ' ' + data['Snow']
        data.pop("Rain")
        data.pop("Snow")
```

It throws so many errors I can't even figure out which one is describing the problem. What am I doing wrong? Is the for loop needed or can Pandas swap a whole column at once

Thanks in advance, I am very, very new to Pandas :)

Comment: The error is because once you have removed `Rain` and `Snow` they no longer, exist yet you are still looking through looking for the Rain and Snow that has already beed removed

Comment: do `data['Precepitation'] = data['Rain'] + ' ' + data['Snow']` then do `data.drop(['Rain', 'Snow'], axis = 1, inplace = True)` and thats it. No looping

Comment: So the code would look as follows: ```data['Precepitation'] = data['Rain'] + ' ' + data['Snow']     data.drop(['Rain', 'Snow'], axis = 1, inplace = True)     ordered_data = data[['Min Temp', 'o Temp', 'Max Temp', 'Preceptation', 'wind_dir', 'wind_speed', 'Air Pressure', 'temp_sun',                 'Year', 'Month', 'Day']]```

Comment: It still throws errors, did I missunderstand?

Comment: Do the first two lines of code throw an error? Note that your data does not have `Rain` You have already deleted it. You need to read the data again from source before running the code. ie `df = pd.read_csv...`

Comment: It seems like the problem is, that Rain and Data are integers. And its trying to add them up. I am just trying to write them next to each other. Is there a way to cast to str? If I cast like ``` str(data['Rain'])``` it puts the whole column in a string I think which of course doesnt work either.

Comment: `data[['Rain', 'Snow']].astype(str).apply(' '.join, axis = 1)`

Answer (score 0):

Probably they are int/float and you have to convert to string.

There are basically two ways:

- `xx = data[['Rain', 'Snow']].astype(str).apply(' '.join, axis = 1)` => 750ms
- `yy=df.Rain.astype('str')+' '+df.Snow.astype('str')` => 200ms

Benchmarked `%%timeit` with 100.000x2 size dataframe

Unless your `data` looping is iterating over different dataframes in a list, it is a slow approach as well